# Como criar uma interação entre 3 páginas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tal interação vai funciona como um tipo de controle remoto, exemplificando seria algo tipo: Página A, B e C

- Na página A o usuário tem acesso aos determinados comandos.
- A página B fica responsável por receber e processar tais comandos.
- E a página C será a página que sofre a ação.

Como funcionaria essa interação? Irei precisar de alguma galeria além do jQuery? Se possível gostaria de um exemplo de como a mesma poderia ser feita.

Um exemplo prático seria:

Página A:

```
<a href="#">clique aqui</a>
```

Página B:
Detecta o click no elemento

Página C:

```
alert("O elemento foi clicado");
```

O jeito mais simples de explicar seria isso.

Comment: Uma forma é, acredito que não tão complexa, utilizar web sockets. Tem como exemplificar pelo menos um comando e qual seria este processamento na página B? Por exemplo, explique um comando, o que deverá ter na página A, o que deverá ser processado na página B e o que deverá ocorrer na página C.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com um exemplo bem simples, com isso já consigo ter a base pra fazer o que preciso.

Comment: Dúvida: a página B deve existir necessariamente? Eu não vejo porquê a mesma deve fazer esta interface. A comunicação entre A e C seria mais interessante, talvez.

Comment: Imaginei a página B como algum script js da página C, mas se puder ser uma solução sem ela, não tem problemas, a página A vai ficar no celular, e a C no desktop do usuário, imaginei a B como a que liga ambas.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a interação entre estas páginas se daria melhor no *server-side* ao invés de tentar fazer pelo *client-side* com JavaScript.

Você pode armazenar os resultados destes comandos da página A no `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`, e pegá-los na página B. A página B faz o que deve ser feito e passa o resultado das operações para a página C. A página C então retorna ao usuário se a operação foi um sucesso ou não. Há um porém: esta solução só funciona em um único dispositivo, já que o `localStorage` e o `sessionStorage` são exclusivos do motor JavaScript do navegador, não podendo ser partilhados.

Isso se assemelha muito ao padrão MVC, mas com certeza somente JavaScript no *client-side* não é a melhor forma de implementá-lo. Recomendo que você dê uma olhada em alguma linguagem de programação que pode rodar servidores, como PHP, Ruby ou Java. Se quiser continuar utilizando JavaScript, recomendo o NodeJS para poder utilizar JavaScript no servidor também.

Vendo pelos seus comentários, você pode fazer duas páginas:

1. A página que fica no celular pode mandar um comando para o servidor;
2. O servidor lê este comando;
3. A página B está periodicamente (a cada 5-10 segundos) perguntando para o servidor o resultado do comando. Quando este se altera, a página muda seu estado.

Esta seria uma das múltiplas soluções que existem para o seu problema, e com certeza não é a melhor. Sugiro que você explique o seu problema um pouco melhor, e que detalhe mais o que você quer fazer.

Comment: 5-10 segundos seria um intervalo muito grande, eu quero criar um tipo de controle remoto para meu player de vídeo, para que o usuário possa manipular ações como play/pause adiantar, voltar, trocar vídeos no celular.

Comment: Como a sua situação é local, então o delay pode ser menor (0,25 - 1 segundo). Uma outra possibilidade é eliminar a página B e ficar somente com a página A, e fazer um programa comum para escutar estes comandos. Eles rodariam como um servidor mas não serviriam páginas; somente escutariam uma porta e esperariam um comando seu para alterar o estado do player.

Comment: Pretendo aplicar esse método a um site online Guilherme, seria possível algo do tipo usando a rede do usuário?

Comment: Se for online, o jeito é utilizar WebSockets. Mas você ainda precisaria do IP da máquina do usuário na rede dele.